# Playing multiple FLVs at the same time feasible?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flv

Is it feasible to play a number of FLV files at the same time on one SWF? Basically I have a brief to create a video banner with a number of FLVs of people playing at the same time but starting at different points in the videos. My concerns are with loading times, memory consumption and the starting of each FLV at a different point and looping it.

The FLVs will be stored on a server and pseudo-streamed.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

eb_dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is feasible, sure.

You should add and start the videos only when they need to be seen.

One suggestion to help might be to put the video files in a cloud space like amazon's s3, but 3MB is pretty small really.

Comment: Thanks daidai, the project is complete now.

Answer (score 0):

If the videos are small (bitrate) and not too many (10 or less) then you should not have any issues with streaming all of them. I think many small videos shouldn't have too much more of an impact on the system than one big video.

Comment: Hi Flassari, thanks for your reply. I was hoping to play three 3mb (around 200px in width) files at the same time and stream them from a streaming server. Do you envisage problems with this?